# EOSIO Boot Not found

Tags: nodeos, eosio.cdt, eosio.system

Hello im not able to find eosio.boot file and even not able to create my own network im following bios boot sequence please help to solve this issue thank you

Comment: https://developers.eos.io/welcome/v2.1/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence following this but stuck on creating account section because im not able to find eosio.boot

Comment: the eosio.boot located in eos repository. its not found  why its happends

Answer (score 1):

For any reason it's missing in the master-branch, if you are using a v2.1.0 version of EOS like the tutorial says, you probably have to switch to tag v2.1.0-rc3 or something similar.

[Helpful link to git tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979642/what-is-git-tag-how-to-create-tags-how-to-checkout-git-remote-tags)

The tutorial for [Boot Sequence
v2.0](https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence) should work as expected from what I can see.

Comment: its should give me eosio.boot file?

Comment: or can i use https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/tutorials/bios-boot-sequence this tutorial . please give me any resource so i can build it thank you

Comment: Both should work. Either use the tutorial for v2.0 as is or use v2.1 and checkout the v2.1-tag from the repository instead of master to get the eosio.boot file.

Comment: thanks men its solved